# Accessing the execution time in model.evalute in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, execution-time

After running `model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose = 1)`, the execution time is displayed on the console, however it is not returned in the list of values. How do I access this execution time value?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's possible, but you can always do it yourself like:

```
from datetime import datetime

startTime = datetime.now()
model.evaluate(...)
elapsed = datetime.now() - startTime
print(elapsed)
```